# Display custom error message when an item has been moved

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have three document libraries:

1. Under Review
2. Published
3. Archive

When I upload a document into "Under Review" library it triggers an email notification to the Site Admin, who can click the email link to review the document. Once he approves the document it is moved from the "Under Review" folder to "Published".

There are many site Admins, if another site Admin want to approve this document from email template which is already Approved, then the message is showing *item does not exist* and that is correct because item is already approved by another Site Admin and document is moved into **Published** so document is not anymore in **Under Review** library , so my question is when the error is showing *item does not exist* instead of that I want to display some custom message like the

> Document is already approved

when any site admin try to approve the document which is already approved.
I have tried with content editor web part but I could not. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please make your question easy-to-understand

Comment: I've done my best to re-write your question, please let me know if it's still accurate. Also, is it a workflow that controls publishing? And which version of SP is this (2010/2013/etc)?

Comment: Hi this is SharePoint 2010, there i have created workflow through SP Designer2010 for triggering the email and moving the document from Under Review to Published, Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not a very neat solution to work with folders or even different libraries. Better use meta data.

What I would do: Add two new columns ("approved" and "archived") to your Library (the same way as on normal lists: libraray => Library Settings => Columns) and than use **one** central document library for all files.

Advantages:

- It solves your problem with the error message, since the file stays where it was uploaded origanlly (no 404)
- You have one clean document library with all your files
- You can simply add three (or more) views and filter the files by the attributes (archived, approved etc.)
- You have one Form for all states
- You easily can add more states
- Other users can send E-Mails with links to the files to each others as well, without getting 404 messages
- It usually is the best practice: Folders are out-dated, meta data are up-to-date ;-)